# What does “finding an element” in $\mathbb Z_n$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I am currently in my last year of high-school and I try to learn Algebra on my own, one of my textbook exercise ask me to

Find elements:

$$ \left\{\;1,\;\frac12,\;\frac14,\;5,\;\sqrt{−2}\right\}\;\in\;\mathbb Z_5$$
I have no idea what $\mathbb Z_5$ neither what does it mean to "**find elements**" in this set. I tried to search on google but I found nothing about this particular notation. Can you please explain me what does this notation and "**finding elements**" mean without giving me the solution to this exercise as I want to do it on my own.

Thanks you very much

Comment: $\mathbb Z_5$ is the field of integers modulo $5$, and consists of the elements $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. So you're being asked to find, for example, for $\frac 12$, an integer k mod $5$ such that $2k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{-2}$ here denotes any number $x$ such that $x^2=-2\color{grey}{=3}$. The symbol $\frac 1  x$ where $x\in \mathbb Z_5$ denotes the multiplicative inverse of $x$ in $\mathbb Z_5$, that is, it denotes the only number $y$ such that $xy=1$. Are you also asking what $\mathbb Z_5$ is?

Comment: What textbook are you using? From the sounds of it, it might be beneficial if you picked up an easier-to-read text.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is the finite field of $5$ elements. So
$$\mathbb{Z}_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\},$$
and we have multiplication and addition performed on the elements modulo 5.

It is clear that $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sqrt{-2}$ do not exist in our set. But, there are elements in our set, that "retain the essence" of the fractions and squareroots.

In the usual rational number field, we have $\dfrac{1}{2}$ defined as the number $2^{-1}$, that is, the multiplicative inverse of $2$, that is, the number $x$ such that $2\times x=1$. So, we need to find a corresponding element, $y$ say, in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ such that $2y\equiv 1\mod 5$.

In the complex number field, $\sqrt{-2}$ is defined as the number $x$ such that $x^2=-2$, so using that as an analogy, we need to find an element in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, say $y$, such that $y^2\equiv -2\equiv3 \mod 5$.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you either skipped over parts of the textbook, or picked up a *very* bad textbook. Any textbook should explain what it *means* by these things before asking you to solve these kind of problems.

But anyway.

$\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the set you get if you start with $\mathbb{Z}$ but then only treat two numbers as *different* if their difference isn't a multiple of $n$. So for example, $2$ and $3$ refer to *distinct* elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, because $2 - 3 = -1$, and that cannot be divided by 5. $2$ and $7$, on the other hand, are the *same*, because $7-2 = 5 = 1 \cdot 5$.

You can easily convince yourself that *every* number in $\mathbb{Z}$ is, over $\mathbb{Z}_n$ equal to one of the numbers $\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}$, and that *none* of these numbers are the same as any other of these numbers. Thus, for most purposes, you can assume that $$
  \mathbb{Z}_n = \left\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}.
$$
But note that this choice of number is not *unique*. There are other sets containing $n$ numbers which *also* have the property that - with the "difference divisible by $n$ means equal" from above - every number of $\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to exactly *one* of the $n$ numbers. You can, for example, also pick
$$
  \mathbb{Z}_n = \left\{0,n+1,2n+2,\ldots,(n-1)^2+n-1\right\}.
$$

The interesting thing about $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is that you can do *arithmetic* within it, and it turns out that you don't need to be carefull *which* of the (very many!) "equal" numbers you do your computations with! The result stays the same (according to the weird "difference divisible by $n$ means equal" rule, of course), no matter which so-called "representative" you pick. Take for example the computation $3\cdot 4 + 7$. In normal arithmetic, this yields 19, which in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is the same as $4$, because $19 - 4 = 15 = 3\cdot 5$. The same computation can be written as $3\cdot (-1) + 2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ (convince yourself that over $\mathbb{Z}_5$, $-1 = 4$ and $2 = 7$), which yields $-1$, and that is over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ the same as $4$.

What the question wants you to do is to find elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which e.g. correspond to $\frac{1}{2}$. The defining property of $\frac{1}{2}$ is that it's a number which, if multiplied with $2$, yields $1$ (this is often called the "multiplicative inverse of $2$"). Your job is to find a number in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which satisfies this. Hint: Compute $2\cdot 3$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$, and see what you get!)

For $\sqrt{-2}$, what they want you to do is to find a number in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ which, if squared, yields $-2$. But, since we're working in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, it doesn't *literally* have to yield $-2$, of course - that would be impossible for any real number -- it just needs to yield a number which is, with the weird equality rule of $\mathbb{Z}_5$, *equal* to $-2$. I won't give you a solution for $\sqrt{-2}$, but for $\sqrt[3]{2}$, a possible solution would be $3$, because $3^3 = 27$, which is the same as $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.